# Launching an Applet fails?

Tags: java, applet, compiler-errors, launch

I am trying to launch an applet from within an applet using the code:

```
        Class applet2 = Class.forName(PostAccess);
    Applet appletToLoad = (Applet)applet2.newInstance();
    appletToLoad.setStub(this);
    setLayout( new GridLayout(1,0));
    add(appletToLoad);
    appletToLoad.init();
    appletToLoad.start();
```

However, this throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at javaapplication1.MainApplet.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainApplet.java:204)
    at javaapplication1.MainApplet.access$100(MainApplet.java:34)
    at javaapplication1.MainApplet$2.actionPerformed(MainApplet.java:68)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for code I could use to launch my applet?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run uncompilable code. The key here is to *not* try to run it but to compile it first and fix the compliation errors *before* trying to run it.

Comment: This is the code Hovercraft Full of Eels? I tried every single way of trying to fix it, but you said, if I have code, I should show you it and you could give suggestions??? This is me trying to launch an applet from within an applet?

Comment: I give up, I am using batch to launch one after the other depending on exit code :'(...

Comment: *"I am trying to launch an applet from within an applet.."*  Why?  What application feature do you wish to offer the end user?  Applets in general are an advanced topic, and what you are attempting (dynamic loading of applets) is also tricky.